# Killing an Excel process using taskkill through VBA

Tags: excel, vba, 32bit-64bit, taskkill

I have a need to kill an Excel process running in background.  I have done it successfully on a machine running 32-bit Office using the code shown below. This code did not execute on a machine running 64-bit Office, and threw an Automation error at the statement Set objProessSet = . . .  (although I think the issue is failure of the immediately preceding statement). My OS is Windows 10.  So, my question is what changes do I need to make to the two Set statements to allow the code to run with 64-bit Office.  Alternately, is there code that will run correctly on both versions of Office?  Another possibility is that a completely different approach is needed for 64-bit Office.

```
Dim objServices As Object, objProcessSet As Object, Process As Object
Dim command As String
Dim cmd As String: cmd = "cmd.exe /S /C taskkill /pid "
Set objServices = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\CIMV2")
Set objProcessSet = objServices.ExecQuery("SELECT ProcessID, FROM Win32_Process WHERE name = ""excel.exe""", , 48)
'loop over all Excel processes - should be only one at most
For Each Process In objProcessSet
    command = cmd & Process.ProcessID
    Call Shell(command, vbNormalFocus)
Next Process
```

Comment: "Win32_Process" is in that line.. what is the equivalent value for 64 bit machine?

Comment: You have to close all instances of MS Excel application. You don't have to do it via "Task manager".